# Changing which Playstation account GTA Online is linked to

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I let my little brother use my playstation to play GTA because I stopped using it, he's basically been playing it for the last year but now I want to play the new Call of Duty game and we can't both use the same account on different playstations at the same time??

He only ever plays GTA Online and I only ever play COD Online - not sure if that makes any difference.

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't migrate your GTA Online content between accounts. Your progress is permanently linked to your PSN account.

You can always try contacting Rockstar and see if they can help you. Access the [GTA V Support Page](https://support.rockstargames.com/categories/200013306), go to `Online Play -> GamePlay Progress -> PS4 -> Contact Us`

If they can't help you, I believe the best solution is to create a new account to play Call of Duty. This way your brother keeps his GTA Online progress and you both can play simultaneously on different devices.